# Looping over the query results set

Tags: coldfusion

I am checking with some work where i am geting the query result as:

```
query
    VALUE
1   #FF6600,#339933,#0033CC,#FF0000,#00CC66,#FF9900,#FFFF00,#00FFFF,#FF66FF
2   Open, Resolved, In-Progress, Escalated, Closed, Re-Opened,Rejected,On-Hold,Locked
```

Now i need to map the 1st row parrallel value to the 2row, I know that this can be done via cfloop or like should i convert it with Array..

Need nested loops, but not sure how it will work

please guide

Comment: So your query returns 1 column called value, with two rows, each containing a list?

Comment: Is there any chance you can instead normalise that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for the data in your question.

```
<cfset NumberOfItems = ListLen(queryname.value[1])>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from=1 to=NumberOfItems index=idx>
Row 1 item is #ListGetAt(queryname.value[1], idx)#<br>
Row 2 item is #ListGetAt(queryname.value[2], idx)#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```